# How to reposition a div upon scroll in bootstrap2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I add a div which is movable based on page scroll in bootstrap2.

Here I saw an [example](http://cross-browser.com/x/examples/floater.php#js). I need to implement similar kind in bootstrap 2 . Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 2 include a '**affix**' library.

You can see the doc here http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#affix

And as it's writed, the affix is working on the page ( vertical left menu )